# How to put a border around each cell in GridView?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and I would like to have a vertical line in between each item. 
I was able to add borders to the headers but I also want the borders for each cell/row in the GridView. See in the image below the borders separating each header don't continue down to the items in the Grid.

[image]

Code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPieces" 
    runat="server"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    CssClass="printTableResults"
    Width="100%"
    DataKeyField="ID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    allowpaging="false">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="printTableHeaderNoBottom" />
      <Columns> 
          <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPieces" HeaderText="Total Qty" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderR" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ></asp:BoundField> 
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualWeight" HeaderText="Gross Wt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>                                              
          <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstRemarks" HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderLOnly" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
     </Columns>
```

So how to do put borders around the items in the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

use CSS

```
* {
border:1px solid #000}
```